# Saxon in ASP.Net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, xquery, saxon

I want to use the Saxon-B XQuery class in my ASP.Net website. But my hosting-provider supports only applications in Medium trust level.

Does someone know if it's possible to use [Saxon-B](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) and IKVM.Net in a medium trust level environment?

Or is there a good alternative XQuery engine for a ASP.Net application in a medium trust level environment?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a lack of XSLT 2.0 and XQuery implementations for .NET. The only ones I've dealt with of are Saxon, and Altova XML (the latter is a COM component, so it won't solve your problem). There seems to be a new kid on the block - XQSharp (http://xqsharp.com/xqsharp/) - might be worth a look, but I've no idea how good that is, and whether it will do what you want.

Comment: Indead, I'm trying http://xqsharp.com/ at the moment. And I'm liking it. Curious when it will become a stable release. Also found thisone on CodePlex: http://qm.codeplex.com/

Comment: I also found this implementation for .NET:
QueryMachine.XQuery - http://qm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XQSharp XQuery API for .NET has now been released.

Comment: Thanks, I 've noticed! Too bad it has become a commercial product :(

Comment: Whilst it is a commercial product, it is still free for non-commercial use.

Comment: XQSharp has been rebranded to XMLprime, I have given up on them due to lack of reponse

Answer (score 0):

The latest XQSharp now includes full XSLT 2.0 support.